# RequireJS: loading a dictionary or definitions script

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, js-amd

I just started expermenting with RequireJS and would like to know if the way I'm loading this dictionary/definitions script (called def/polygons.js) with is the most convenient/eficient or not.

It works, I can instantiate a 'Drawer' and have access to 'polygons' but that 'polygons' variable *I THINK* is global and I don't feel this may be the best practice... any help will be appreciated :)

File where I require 'def/polygons.js'

```
/*
 *      Drawer Class Definition
 *
 *
 **/
define([
    'modules/canvas', 
    'def/polygons'
    ], function(Canvas, polygons) {

    'use strict'

    function Drawer(canvasSettings) {

        if (!this instanceof Drawer) {
            throw new TypeError("Drawer constructor cannot be called as a function.");
        }

        this.canvas = new Canvas(canvasSettings);
        this.polygons = polygons;
    }


    Drawer.prototype = {

        /* Repoint base constructor back to the original constructor function */
        constructor: Drawer,

        do: function() {
            console.log("This is just a test");
            console.log(this.polygons);
        }
    };


    return Drawer;
});
```

And this is the script where I define the polygons dictionary:

```
/*
 *      Polygon Definitions
 *
 *
 **/
define(function() {

    return {        
        name: 'square',
        position: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        points: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },{
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },{
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },{
            x: 0,
            y: 0            
        }]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I THINK is global and I don't feel this may be the best practice

The beauty and power of Require.js is that it helps you to avoid polluting the global scope. With that being said, your `polygons` class is *definitely not* being put on the global scope.

Because you've defined it like so:

```
define(function() {

    return {        
        name: 'square',
        position: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        points: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },{
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },{
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },{
            x: 0,
            y: 0            
        }]
    }

});
```

This module is simply *returning* your polygon object - nothing is being pushed onto the global scope.

And when you call to access your script here:

```
define([
    'modules/canvas', 
    'def/polygons'
    ], function(Canvas, polygons) {

    ...
```

Your `polygon` object is only being instantiated within the particular scope of this module.

So with all that being said, your `polygon` object is not being pushed onto the global scope so don't worry, it is contained within the scope of the particular module(s) that you call for it in.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick, in that case I will incorporate this practice from now on ;)